# Confused about Django REST authentication, JWT and HTTP cookies

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework

So after researching the best practices of authentication/security, it seems like storing the JWTs created by the backend in the localStorage is not secure, and thus, HTTP Cookies should be used, kind of. The problem is, that the simpleJWT package does not do cookies. Did not find any other up to date packages, which can deal with this task. So what should i do? Ditch the JWTs and use DRF's built-in Session Authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is a misunderstanding that `httpOnly` cookies prevent the XSS attack. It is not true. In the case of the XSS successful attack, the hacker can use `httpOnly` cookies to perform malicious requests.
- In the case of `localStorage` and XSS attack the hacker can directly read the auth tokens, and use them for malicious requests.
- So malicious requests can be done for both types: `localStorage` and cookies `httpOnly`.
- What is more, if cookies with `httpOnly` are used, malicious requests can be done from other sources (the Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)). Such an attack doesn't apply in the case of the `localStorage`.

The comparison of `localStorage` vs `cookies` is from my article: [React Token-Based Authentication to Django REST API Backend](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/react-token-based-authentication-django/).

The issue to add cookies `httpOnly` is open in simplejwt repo: [link to issue](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/issues/71).

If you can use DRF session-based, you should use it. It is a battle-tested solution. If you want to use token-based auth, you can store the token in `localStorage` and it will be secure as it can be.